# Receiving IndexOutOfBoundsException when removing item from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a list of values. I want to remove the list item when check box is unclicked:

```
ArrayList<SalesRoutes> routeList = new ArrayList<SalesRoutes>();
ArrayList<String> selectedRoutes = new ArrayList<String>();
 routeList =getSalesRoute();
for (int i = 0; i < routeList.size(); i++) {
         CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
   ch.setId(i);
   ch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                    if(arg0.isChecked()){   
                        Log.i("add", routeList.get(arg0.getId()).getRouteCode());
                        selectedRoutes.add(routeList.get(arg0.getId()).getRouteCode());
                        System.out.println("----add ----" + selectedRoutes);
                    }else {
                        selectedRoutes.remove(arg0.getId());
                        Log.i("remove", routeList.get(arg0.getId()).getRouteCode());
                        System.out.println("----remove ----" + selectedRoutes);
                    }
                }
            });
   }
```

Here I got `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because selectedRoutes is selected CheckBox values

```
   selectedRoutes   
   [R0002]
```

routeList displays a list of routes on the screen. It fetches the route from a db.

Example routeList:

```
  Route List
  R0001
  R0002   // selected this one ID is 1
  R0003
```

calling remove from selectedRoutes(1).

```
   selectedRoutes.remove(arg0.getId());
```

Here selectedRoutes only contains one record, which means there is no index 1.

**How can I remove this?**

Comment: does `arg0.getId()` contain `0` in first example and `1` in second?

Comment: arg0.getId()  will return checkbox id.I have 2 arraylist 'selectedRoutes' and 'routelist`

Comment: What is the full exception? Line numbers, stack trace, error message, please post all of it.

Comment: Haran, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this section of code:

```
selectedRoutes.remove(arg0.getId());
Log.i("remove", routeList.get(arg0.getId()).getRouteCode());
System.out.println("----remove ----" + selectedRoutes);
```

You're hinging that on the (usually incorrect) assumption that the index of your route in your list of potential routes is the same as the index of your route in the list of selected routes. Instead, you'll want to get the route code of the route in your potential list of routes at that index, then iterate through your list of selected routes (which are actually just Strings containing route codes), and remove the index where the two match up. Code would look something like this:

```
String routeCode = routeList.get(arg0.getId()).getRouteCode();
index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < selectedRoutes.size(); i++) {
    if(routeCode.equals(selectedRoutes.get(i)) {
        index = i;
            break;
    }
}
if(index > -1)
    selectedRoutes.remove(index);
Log.i("remove", routeCode);
System.out.println("----remove ----" + selectedRoutes);
```

Comment: Thanks.Its greate.Working fine..I should have done into the HashMap. In Android I want to set ArrayList that's why i selected this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier if you created **selectedRoutes** to be a collection of the same objects `ArrayList<SalesRoutes> selectedRoutes`. Since both collections would contain the references to the same object you could remove the object by its reference:

```
salectedRoutes.remove(routeList.get(arg0.getId()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling ArrayList.remove(int location) will remove the object at that location in the array. It **does not** remove a object by it's Id value.

It appears you are adding an object to the arraylist at an index position returned by .getRouteCode()

But then you are trying to remove an object at an index position returned by .getId().

The two don't sync up.

Comment: No.'getRouteCode()' contain list of routes with check box.I want to make another arraylist for selected check box value.

Comment: To be honest I think you need to read the Javadoc for Adding/Removing objects from an ArrayList by Index position and by Object.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `ArrayList.remove(int index)` and `ArrayList.remove(Object o)`.

Comment: I precisely put arraylist name:I have two arrayList.One is for displaying route another one for selected route(checkbox selected value)